# getkey() works well when program started from command line but not from IDLE

Tags: python

I've been looking for possibilities of detecting keypresses in both blocking and non-blocking way and among some other similar PyPI libraries I've found the [getkey package](https://pypi.org/project/getkey/) which (at first) seemed to do what I need.

Although the library really does work well when the program is started from the command line (on Windows 10 + Python 2.7), when the same program is started from IDLE `getkey()` always (**even if nothing is pressed**) returns this character: `˙`.

Here is the code I used to test the library:

```python
from getkey import getkey, keys
from time import sleep
sleep(2)
print "Start"
key = getkey(blocking=True)
while key != "m":
    if key == keys.UP:
        print "UP"
    else:
        print key
    sleep(2)
    print "Next..."
    key = getkey(blocking=True)
print "End"
```

**Note:**
Since I will use the code on Rasbperry Pi (Linux) I was looking for a way to detect keypresses in a program started **from command line** but I'd like to be able to first test the algorithms on Windows - that's why I was looking for a **cross platform** solution. Additionally, I'd like to avoid buffering of pressed keys when using non-blocking call as in `key = getkey(blocking=False)` but all the keys pressed during the `sleep()` are later detected one by one as well - which is not what I want. In other words, I am really looking for some similar library which would detect only if the key is pressed **in the moment of execution** of the command for reading the keyboard. But that is another topic, here I would like to know **why the same code produces different result when started from IDLE compared to when started from the command line**.

**EDIT:**
The output when the code is started from within IDLE is:

```
Start
˙
Next...
˙
Next...
˙
Next...
˙
Next...
˙
Next...
˙
```

and so on forewer (**even without any keyboard input**).

The output when the program is started from the command line is as one would expect, e.g.:

```
Start
a
Next...
z
Next...
UP
Next...
End
```

That is the output if the keys pressed were: "a", "z", "arrow up", "m".

Comment: Can you include the actual examples of output you get when testing, and the desired output please?

Comment: @ladygremlin: Here you are the example of output in case when the program is started from IDLE and when it is started from command line.

Comment: Thank you! That helps me understand what you're seeing.